# Ramda: Split a list to segments

Tags: ramda.js

If we have a list such as:

```
[
  {
    type: 'a',
  },
  {
    type: 'a',
  },
  {
    type: 'b',
  },
  {
    type: 'a',
  }
]
```

... and we want to segment it to create a list, such that the new list is made up of each segment of the initial list, here split by type, looking like:

```
[
  [
    {
      type: 'a',
    },
    {
      type: 'a',
     },
  ],
  [
    {
      type: 'b',
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      type: 'a',
    }
  ]
]
```

I'd like to create a general purpose 'segmenting' function, which takes a function to compare two items, and determine whether or not a new segment is required. Here, the 'segmenter' for that function simply compares type.

I can write that in vanilla javascript, **but is there a good way to do this with Ramda**?

```js
const data = [
  {
    type: 'a',
  },
  {
    type: 'a',
  },
  {
    type: 'b',
  },
  {
    type: 'a',
  }
];

const segmentBy = segmenter => items => {
  const segmentReducer = (prev = [], curr) => {
    let lastSegment = [];
    let lastItem = null;
    
    try {
      lastSegment = prev[prev.length - 1];
      lastItem = lastSegment[lastSegment.length - 1];
    } catch (e) {
      return [...prev, [curr]];
    }
    const requiresNewSegment = segmenter(lastItem, curr);
    
    if (requiresNewSegment) {
      return [...prev, [curr]];
    }
    
    return [...prev.slice(0, prev.length - 1), [...lastSegment, curr]];
  };
  
  return items.reduce(segmentReducer, []);
};

const segmentByType = segmentBy((a, b) => a.type !== b.type);
const segments = segmentByType(data);
  
console.dir(segments);
```

Comment: `R.splitWhen` could probably help here!!!

Comment: @Hitmands I imagine that could be useful, though I image [`groupWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupWith) to be the easier of the two for this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Ramda you can use R.groupWith:

> Takes a list and returns a list of lists where each sublist's elements
>   are all satisfied pairwise comparison according to the provided
>   function. Only adjacent elements are passed to the comparison
>   function.

```js
const data = [{"type":"a"},{"type":"a"},{"type":"b"},{"type":"a"}];

const segmentByType = R.groupWith(R.eqBy(R.prop('type')));
const segments = segmentByType(data);
  
console.dir(segments);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

In vanilla, the main problem is when to add a new subarray to the accumulator. You need to add another subarray when it's the 1st item, or if `segmenter` returns `true`.

```js
const data = [{"type":"a"},{"type":"a"},{"type":"b"},{"type":"a"}];

const segmentBy = segmenter => items =>
  items.reduce((r, item, i, arr) => {
    if(i === 0 || segmenter(item, arr[i - 1])) r.push([]);
    
    r[r.length - 1].push(item);
    
    return r;
  }, []);

const segmentByType = segmentBy((a, b) => a.type !== b.type);
const segments = segmentByType(data);
  
console.dir(segments);
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for both the ramda code and the improved vanilla example!

Comment: You're welcome :) See update. Since Ramda functions are curried, you don't actually need to explicitly pass segmenter. See update.

Comment: Very nice indeed! Glad to see it can be done so neatly with ramda